# Am I publishing a this if I'm adding an Integer field to an outside collection?

Tags: java

Consider this:

```
public static Set<B> set;

class A {
  private B b = new B();
  void someMethod();
}

class B {
 public void f() { A.this.someMethod(); }
}
```

Then I'm doing

```
A a  = new A();
set.add(b);
```

Now I believe a won't be garbage collected until `b` is removed from set because we may still want to call `b.f()` and this will need `A.this`.

Now replace `B` with `Integer` so we have

```
public static Set<B> set;

class A {
   private Integer b = new Integer(6000);
}
```

and again

```
A a  = new A();
set.add(b);
```

Now, in the same scenario will `A` also never be garbage collected until the `Integer b` is removed from the set?

Comment: The first example you have now won't compile. The notation `A.this` applies only within a inner class. `B` is not an inner class of `A` in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
set.add(a.n);
```

you are copying a reference to the integer (that may be) referenced by `n`. There is no, implicit or explicit, back-reference to the object referenced by `a`.

If the object referenced by `a` is eligible for GC, its `finalize` method will be run when the GC runs.

Comment: But will it be eligible if I have placed its a.n into the set?

Comment: @alex You are not placing its `a.n`. You are placing a copy of the value of the reference stored in the field `n` of the object referenced by `a`. An object is completely unrelated to any references to it.

Comment: I'm placing a reference to n. The n is a field of a. If a gets garbage collected n will become invalid. Therefore, a will not get garbage collected. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Alex `a.n` is an expression. When evaluated, it resolves to a reference to an object (or `null`). Think of it as simply a memory address. A memory address has not other fields or relations. It's simply a number.

Comment: n in a.n is a field of a. It is also not static. Imagine a.n is not Integer but some Object. In this object there can be a method using a through A.this. So in this case A won't be garbage collected. Why then A will be garbage collected if a.n is Integer?

Comment: @Alex Ok, so now you are bringing _inner_ classes into this. `A.this` is only possibly if the executing code is within a instance method of an inner class. In that case the object referenced by `a.n` would have an implicit field to its enclosing class. If the inner class instance was reachable, then its enclosing instance would also be reachable and therefore not eligible for GC. **But this is not the case with Integer**, which is an independent class with no relation to an instance of `A`.